# Self-contained JWT for oauth

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am fairly new to wso2is.
I added an SP with oauth/oidc and got the client credentials.
But when I call the token endpoint to generate an access token (client_credentials flow), I get a guid/reference token. How do I get a self-contained JWT?

Also, the discovery endpoint and introspection not available in 5.2.0?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there are is no out of the box solution to get self-contained JWT as an access token from WSO2 Identity Server. However, we have an extension point[1] to write one to suit your requirements.

If I give you the steps in short,

1. Write an accessToken issuer class implementing this interface. Instead of the GUID, you return the signed JWT.
2. Create jar and add it to IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins
3. Add the fully qualified classname to IS_HOME/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml by adding a `<IdentityOAuthTokenGenerator>` tag under `<OAuth>` section.

Check out the default accessTokenIssuer code to get an idea[2]. Discovery endpoint and Introspection endpoint have been added in IS 5.3.0. Try out the alpha version from [3]

[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/676c4d845842556a560874804373a422940492a9/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/OauthTokenIssuer.java#L25-L25

[2] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/676c4d845842556a560874804373a422940492a9/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/OauthTokenIssuerImpl.java

[3] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/download/v5.3.0-alpha/wso2is-5.3.0-alpha.zip

---

**Update**

Follow this blog post https://medium.com/@hasinthaindrajee/self-contained-access-tokens-with-wso2-identity-server-82111631d5b6#.s0q3xt6od to get your use case done :)

Comment: Thanks for the details!

Any reason why JWT as an access token is not supported? What's the discovery URL - I tried few including sever/oauth2/<well-known> but didn't work.

Comment: it is in the form https://localhost:9443/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:admin@localhost&rel=http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer